# JQuery dropdown menu is readonly but not disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got a page that has a form on it, and if a user is logged in as a non-admin account, the fields should be read-only.  All of the text fields are behaving properly, but the dropdown menus still allow the value to be changed.

```
function setReadonly(){
    //Text Fields
    id_first_name.readOnly=true;
    id_middle_name.readOnly=true;
    id_last_name.readOnly=true;
    id_last_4_ssn.readOnly=true;
    //Dropdowns
    $("#id_gender").attr("readonly", true);
    $("#id_department").attr("readonly", true);
}
```

The drop-down bars are greyed out like the text fields, but the option can be changed as usual.  I've tried doing

```
$("#id_gender").attr("disabled", true);
$("#id_gender").attr("disabled", "disabled");
$("#id_gender").prop("disabled", "disabled");
```

The two attr's didn't solve the problem, and the prop failed because I'm running v1.5

Comment: The answer below is correct, it should work fine even with `attr()`, which you shouldn't use, you should use `prop`, so the issue is most likely the wrong selector as you're missing the hash -> **http://jsfiddle.net/Y3JTT/**

Answer (score 1):

```
$("id_gender").attr("disabled", true);
$("id_gender").attr("disabled", "disabled");
$("id_gender").prop("disabled", "disabled");
```

All the above statements have selectors that will be applied to tags "id_gender"

But from the function that you have posted in your question I believe that the above 3 statements are to be applied to the element with id "id_gender". So try simply adding the "#" before the selector are following which is the correct syntax:

```
$("#id_gender").attr("disabled", true);
$("#id_gender").attr("disabled", "disabled");
$("#id_gender").prop("disabled", "disabled");
```

Please let me know if this was helpful or if you have any queries.

Comment: Just forgot to include the #'s in the message, the code does have them but they don't work.

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle

Comment: It was an issue with timing an ajax callback, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I was setting the fields to read-only and disabled before the ajax call returned the form data.  When it tried to fill in data to a disabled field, it automatically enabled it.  The fields all stayed read-only, but any disabled attr's were removed.

Needed to do

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function(){
    [if user.readonly] setReadonly();
});
```

$("#id_gender").attr("disabled", true) worked fine.